# Unable to symlink '/usr/bin/python3' to '/home/ubuntu/my-env/bin/python3'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, deployment, aws-code-deploy

I have Django application which is getting deployed on Code Deploy.

In logs i get an error saying 'Unable to symlink '/usr/bin/python3' to '/home/ubuntu/my-env/bin/python3'

Any clues anyone, how to fix this issue,,..?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I guess you used the `ln -s` command in Linux. And you want to link `/home/ubuntu/my-env/bin/python3` to `/usr/bin/python3`.

When we use `ln -s` command, we should check if 2rd arg(`/usr/bin/python3`) exists.

So, I think the `/usr/bin/python3` file in your system exists aready. You should delete it and attempt to redeploy.

```py
# 1. enter /usr/bin
cd /usr/bin/

# 2. search python3 file
ls | grep python3

# 3. delete it 
rm -rf python3

# 4. redeploy
```

Answer (score 0):

removal helped in my case /home/ubuntu/my-env/bin/python3